# Select an attribute value in a specific row specific column and specific input

Tags: jquery, html-table

Given a table with a plenty of row like this:

```
<tr>
<td><input class="szoveg" type=text name=p1 maxlength=2 size=2 value="7"></td>
<td><select class="szoveg" name=p2><option value=1 selected>Live<option value=2>Teszt</select></td>
<td><input class="gomb" type=submit value=Modify></td>
<td><input type=hidden name=s_attr value=s_value></td>
<td><input type=hidden name=m_attr value=m_value></td>
<td><input type=hidden name=id value="AAAR7u"></td>
<td><input class="btn" value=Del></td>
</tr>
```

I would like to get:

- **s_value** of the **s_attr**
- *Éles* of the *p2* select input type
- *AAR7u* of the *id*

and so on, I need almost each of the values inside the `<td>` tags, I want to give as an argument and invoke a function with it...

How can I achieve getting with jQuery?

Now I can get the row only with this jQuery selector:

```
$('#table_id tr').eq(1)
```

But I need also the values....
Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tr = $('#table_id tr:eq(1)');
tr.find("input[name=s_attr]").val();
tr.find.. etc...
```

Comment: ok, but this will do it for all of the rows, and i need only e.g. the second or third row...
So e.g. how can i use this with that? 
$('#table_id tr').eq(1)

Comment: OK, thank you man, seems fine!

You have any knowledge of a 'one liner' solution? or only this?:)
(i will upvate instantly after your answer not related to the content of the answer) thanks!
Or maybe easier solution? (not find)

Answer (score 2):

`$("#table_id tr").eq(1).find("td").eq(3).find("input").val()`
  gives you the value of the input in row 1 column 3 of your table ( or whatever row and column number you enter ).

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute selector and the .val() function

```
$('[name=s_attr]').val()
$('[name=p2]').val()
$('[name=id]').val()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how can i use this with my row selector?
$('#table_id tr').eq(1)??

Comment: Do you just want the value of whatever input field is in a specific table row? If so you can do $('#table_id tr:eq(1) :input').val(), which will give you the value of the input field in the first row. This of course assumes that you only have one input field in each row

Comment: the bad thing that i can have multiple input field: ( but thanks for your help... Anyway appreciate your help and upvoted