# How to post the value of a specific cell of a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to capture the value of two cells from a table.  My table looks like this:

```
    <table id="searchByLocationResults" class="table table-hover table-striped" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">View Detail</th>
                <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col" style="display:none;">Location ID</th>
                <th scope="col" style="display:none;">Item Type ID</th>
            </tr>
            @For Each item In Model
                Dim currentItem = item    
                @<tr>
                     <td><a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="viewDetails(this)">View Detail</a></td>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.COUNT)
                     </td>
                     <td style="display:none;" class="locationID">
                         @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Unique_Location_ID)
                     </td>
                     <td style="display:none;" class="itemType">
                         @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Item_Type_Identifier)
                     </td>
                </tr>
            Next
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you can see there is a 'view details' button on each row.  What I need to do is capture the `display:none` values in the cells with `class=locationID` and `class=itemType` when the button is clicked, only for the row that the button is clicked on.  I have seen multiple solutions on stack over flow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750623/select-a-row-from-html-table-and-send-values-onclick-of-a-button), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322622/select-an-attribute-value-in-a-specific-row-specific-column-and-specific-input) and quite a few others.  Most of these are dealing with capturing an entire row of values.

I have tried a few different scripts:

```
 function viewDetails(clickedRow) {
                var locationID = $(this).find(".selected td:.locationID").val();
                alert(locationID);
```

and:

```
function viewDetails(clickedRow) {
    var locationID = tr.find(".locationID").val();
    alert(locationID);
```

as well as a few others.

How do you capture the values of the cells `locationID` and `itemType` for the row that 'View Details' is clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to try the [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/). This only works if the buttons and text areas have unique classes so the count works correctly. Then once you have the index use the [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the data.

```
var index = $(".btn-sm").index();
var locationId = $(".locationID").eq(index).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You just need to use the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method in Jquery

```
function viewDetails(clickedRow) {
    var locationID = tr.find(".locationID").text();
    alert(locationID);
```

Comment: this does not work, I never hit the alert.  I am hitting the function though, verified with an alert before the variable assignment.  And I've quadruple checked the spelling.

Comment: Sorry.  I assumed your tr was already obtained at the row in question.